# Can't understand why Li need to be in caps can, can anyone explain?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function toggleClassDoneOnAndOff(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
        event.target.classList.toggle("done");
    }
}
ul.addEventListener("click", toggleClassDoneOnAndOff);
```

Can anyone explain why LI need to be in caps?

I just try to find the answer but dont understand the explanation

Comment: It's just the way JavaScript was built.

Comment: Because `==` is case-sensitive. Since the function returns an uppercase name, you have to compare it with an uppercase string.

Comment: It's [the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-tagname) that defines it to be [returned in uppercase letters](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element-html-uppercased-qualified-name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Element: tagName property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) documentation:

> For DOM trees which represent HTML documents, the returned tag name is always in the canonical upper-case form. For example, tagName called on a `<div>` element returns "DIV"

> The tag names of elements in an XML DOM tree are returned in the same case in which they're written in the original XML file. If an XML document includes a tag `"<SomeTag>"`, then the tagName property's value is "SomeTag".

Answer (score 3):

because behind HTML, all its elements are described in an **object** model, directly accessible in javascript. To simplify [a lot] all HTML objects are described in javascript, whose particularity is to be case sensitive. therefore the prototype of a UL element has always been capitalized.

In reality, the first html browser is written in C, which is also case sensitive (see [Robert Cailliau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cailliau) -> [first web browser MacWWW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacWWW))

You can also use a generic method [matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) which uses css syntax where lowercase is accepted:

```js
ul.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
  {
  if (event.target.matches('li'))
    {
    event.target.classList.toggle('done');
    }
  });
```

in comments:

> Do you have any references for your rationale? 'therefore the prototype of a UL element has always been capitalized.' What does that mean? The Spec simply specifies that 'The tagName getter steps are to return this’s HTML-uppercased qualified name.' – pilchard
>
> > specs are based on real code; there is a prototype object for each HTML element having names written in uppercase letters. Even If the HTML interpreter accepts that we write tag names in lowercase letters, it remains obliged to fetch the prototype having a name written in uppercase letters, which proto uses a get tagName() method to return the object name. Objects can only have a unique name, and this one is made of uppercase letters.

see in `console.log( document.querySelector('li'))` (Firefox)
[image]

tagName will return an uppercase value
[image]

see HTML Element prototype... (HTML **LI** Element prototype is herited from HTML Element prototype)
[image]

herited from Dom Element...
[image]

the tagName value comes from a get method.
[image]

Then you would have to look at source codes of the javascript engines (SpiderMonkey for firefox) to check where this value really comes from in capital letters, but we already have a clue: the name of the HTML**LI**Elementprototype prototype does indeed contain the value `LI` in capital letters; and I'm willing to bet a bunch of peanuts that there's a connection between those uppercase letters and the value returned by the `get tagName()`.

Comment: Do you have any references for your rationale? *'therefore the prototype of a UL element has always been capitalized.'* What does that mean? The [Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-tagname) simply specifies that *'The tagName getter steps are to return `this`’s HTML-uppercased qualified name.'*

Comment: @pilchard I have uodated my answer...

Comment: I take your point but your logic is a little tangled. The spec does not describe the code, rather the code implements the spec which is by design language agnostic. Also the all caps `LI` in the constructor name is at best tangentially connected to the uppercase `tagName` and is based on PascalCasing. Elements whose names are not acronyms don't have the same correlation ie `HTMLDivElement` whose `tagName` is still uppercase `DIV`. I'm still glad you expanded your answer, but the heart of it is that it is uppercase because that is what the Spec requires.

Comment: @pilchard Yes, you are right and your reference with HTMLDivElement is a good counterexample. I got a little carried away on this one; let's say that my coder temperament took over. For the record, the DIV tag didn't exist in the beginning of HTML. Microsoft introduced it in IE in order to make pages incompatible with competing browsers, replacing the LAYER tag.

Comment: @pilchard Otherwise I am also the author of software (at Alsys, now defunct) which took me almost 3 years to write. Believe me, the specs have evolved a lot during these 3 years. Ultimately, it's really the lines of code that define the specifications.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple: the `tagName` property is defined to always be in all-caps, and `===` (and `==` for that matter) compares strings exactly; `'a' === 'A'` is false.

You could do the comparison other ways; Mister Jojo in their answer suggests calling the `matches` method on the target rather than using its `tagName` property at all. But you could still use `tagName`, and just explicitly convert to lowercase:

```
if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "li")
```

That's doing extra work, though. Seems easier to just use the all-caps version, since that's guaranteed to be what `.tagName` contains.